# Unity Error: X server took longer than 2002 milliseconds to respond to

Tags: unity-game-engine

Whenever I launch Unity Editor, I always get multiple of the same error message in my console, and one NullReferenceException.

[image: error]

What are these and how can I fix them? I tried searching the web and didn't find anything. Can I safely ignore them?

My machine is decently powerful with 16 GB ram, i5 8th gen @ 1.8 GHz. Not sure if my machine is just laggy or if these are legitimate errors.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Is it only happening once on lunching of Unity? In that case I would say ignore them ;) looks quite "Running Unity on Ubuntu" specific to me

Comment: It happens on launch and whenever I move around windows or press certain menu components.

Comment: file a bug report to unity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Confirmed bug by Unity Editor developer - *bug report already made*. The problem has existed since version 2020.1.13f1.

Until it is fixed you could either ignore it or downgrade to Unity version 2020.1.12f1 (last version without the bug).

The version 2020.1.12f1 is no longer listed in UnityHub, although it is possible to download it from command line:

```
$ ./UnityHub.AppImage unityhub://2020.1.12f1/55b56f0a86e3
```

If you don't have UnityHub it can be downloaded [here](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download).

Relates to: [post on unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/buggy-editor-since-version-2020-1-13-x-server-freezes-when-opening-moving-layout.1032868).

Answer (score 2):

Unity Editor dev here. This is a bug. Please report it using Help->Report a Bug. We've made some changes in the Linux editor recently, and this message is part of it. Not something you should normally see.